# prevent next script execution until first one finish

Tags: php

At first, sorry for my English.

I have one php script that executing about 5 minutes. When I lost connection or abort executing in browser script is still running - that's OK for me.

But how can I check if this script is running and do not allow it to run once again until it finish?

What this script do:
read source code from a lot of web pages and write some data to mysql database

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What script are you talking about? JS

Comment: Please provide more information about what your script is and what it is doing. Provide examples of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It will only keep running if you've set ignore_user_abort(true) and set_timeout(0) - otherwise it will stop unpredicatably (and terminate/rollback any incomplete database transactions).

If you want to make sure it runs to completion, don't run it from a browser - run it from the command line or via atd/crond.

Comment: Changing the php.ini has got nothing to do with the measures I suggested.

Comment: Ok, but is there any option to check that php script is still execitung?